# how to develop a p2p video chat using flash media server

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, media

I would like to develop a small p2p chat using flash media sever 4.0.  There are many p2p video chat samples using cirrus.  Please help me if you know how to do it with flash media server,not cirrus.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Just I am giving step to develop a P2P video chat using the Flash Media Server 4.0 (or any version).

1. First of all setup your Flash Media Server.
2. Start writing client (flash/Flex) Appliation using the ActionScript 3.0.
3. Put video display control in your ui
4. write down the code for connection with FMS using the NetConnection Class of Flash ActionScript 3.0
5. Start capturing the Video from your web-cam using the Camera class
6. Create your NetStream Class Instance and attach the your camera (web-cam view) to the Strem and Video component.
7. Start Publishing of your web-cam view using the your NetStream Instance.
8. Now Put another viewo component to get another person cam view.
9. subscribe the remote person published live steam to display in your client application using the NetStream. and attach the your subscribed stream to the second one video component to display....

Please just gone througth given below inbuild class / libraries before start development:
1. NetConnection
2. NetStream
3. Camera
some another display obejct class and Video component.